# RxJava: Observe single execution from multiple observers

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have to do some configuration before my app is operational, for example installing an exception handler. Because my app has multiple entry points (an `Activity`, a `SyncAdapter`) I want to do this configuration only once in my `Application` class and observe it on the entry points (`Activity`, `SyncAdapter`). If the configuration has already been completed when the entry point starts, the information about the outcome should still be available.

That's the `Observable` in the `Application` class (RxJava 2):

```
ConnectableObservable<Boolean> observable = Observable.create(…)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .cache()
        .publish();
observable.connect();
```

That's the observer in the `Activity`:

```
observable.subscribe(…);
observable.connect();
```

And that's the observer in the `SyncAdapter`:

```
observable.blockingSubscribe(…);
observable.connect();
```

The `Observable` and the observer in the `Activity` are doing what I want, even completing immediately if the observer connects after the `Observable` has finished its work. But the observer in the `SyncAdapter` blocks forever if it connects after the `Observable` has finished its work.

My questions:

- What am I missing?
- Is there a way to solve this problem in a more idiomatic way, e.g. by using a `Completable`?

Comment: Could you please show the implementation of Observable.create(…)? Why would you use blockinSub in SyncAdapter but not in Activity? If you miss the "true", you will be blocking forever due to the hot nature of the observable (publish-connect).

Answer (score 0):

you are most likely deadlocking her:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

In combination with:

```
observable.blockingSubscribe(…);
```

You start the subscription on the thread-pool. The generated value will be moved to the ui-loop. Meanwhile you subscribe on to the observable and block the subscription on the ui-loop (main-thread). While you are blocking the subscription, no value can be pushed because the main-thread is already blocked: deadlock.

Why not use:

```
observable.filter(aBoolean -> aBoolean)
                .subscribe(aBoolean -> {
                    // is True so do stuff here::::::
                });
```

Please have a look at a possible solution:
https://gist.github.com/SergejIsbrecht/2d6a20283d7c3ea304af0cf54f0650b4